# Custom button and html with [settings api plugin]

Tags: settings-api

We are trying to improve the backend of a small plugin of ours via the settings api and we are using Tareqs http://tareq.wedevs.com/2012/06/wordpress-settings-api-php-class/ Settings API for it.
We don't seem to figure out how to implement a custom button that after saving the settings it executes the plugin. This is one "Save" and one "Save & Execute" button.
Also, there are no HTML or plain text types in the array, so we are not sure how to implement a kind of documentation tab with plain HTML info.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the plugin to add a "Save & Execute" button, but not sure what will you do with that. As the PHP class doesn't do anything for saving the options, WordPress handles it by default. So it's tricky that how you'll implement the execution.

You can add a `html` type field for documentation.

```
array(
    'name' => 'docs',
    'label' => __( 'Documentation', 'wpuf' ),
    'type' => 'html',
    'desc' => 'Your docs here'
)
```